# cakephp captca validation

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using the captcha component.

```
<?php

function create($width='120',$height='40',$characters='6') {

    $code = $this->generateCode($characters); 

    /* font size will be 75% of the image height */
    $font_size = $height * 0.70;

    $image = @imagecreate($width, $height) or die('Cannot initialize new GD image stream');

    /* set the colours */
    $background_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 220, 220, 220);               
    $text_color       = imagecolorallocate($image, 10, 30, 80);
    $noise_color      = imagecolorallocate($image, 150, 180, 220);

    /* generate random dots in background */
    for( $i=0; $i<($width*$height)/3; $i++ ) {
        imagefilledellipse($image, mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), 1, 1, $noise_color);
    }

    /* generate random lines in background */
    for( $i=0; $i<($width*$height)/150; $i++ ) {
        imageline($image, mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), $noise_color);
    }

    /* create textbox and add text */
    $textbox = imagettfbbox($font_size, 0, dirname(__FILE__).'/'.$this->font, $code) or die('Error in imagettfbbox function');
    $x       = ($width - $textbox[4])/2;
    $y       = ($height - $textbox[5])/2;
    $y       -= 5;
    imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, $x, $y, $text_color, dirname(__FILE__).'/'.$this->font , $code) or die('Error in imagettftext function');

    /* output captcha image to browser */
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($image);
    imagedestroy($image);

    $this->Controller->Session->write('security_code',$code);
}
```

The captca is created successfully, but when I try to validate it I got an error because `$code` is not stored in the session. I do not understand why this is happening.

Comment: thats not really good code here. you should not send headers etc while the script is still working. that's why you dont manually send any headers in 2.x and let the response class do it.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$this->Controller->Session->write('security_code', $code);
```

to this:

```
$this->Session->write('security_code', $code);
```

Also, ensure that you've added the SessionHelper to your $helpers array.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CakePHP 1.x, it seems that your application is sending output to browser before the header() function being called to generate image. In that case you need to move the session creation line to above *header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');* to look like the following:

```
imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, $x, $y, $text_color, $this->font , $code) or die('Error in imagettftext function');
/* output captcha image to browser */
$this->Controller->Session->write('security_code',$code);
@ob_end_clean(); //clean buffers, as a fix for 'headers already sent errors..'
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

If you are using CakePHP 2.x download updated version of captcha component from author's website www.devarticles.in/cakephp/simple-captcha-component-for-cakephp/

Answer (score 0):

I have faced some issue and get rid of that by changing location of session storing line

```
function create($width='120',$height='40',$characters='6') {

    $code = $this->generateCode($characters); 
    $this->Controller->Session->write('security_code',$code);

    //.....rest of code will remain same
}
```